# Unable to launch Instruments 'Time Profiler' for an application using Subprocess Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, instruments

I need to introduce trace logging for an application programmatically through python in an asynchronous way, i.e. not wait for it but open as a separate process. I can launch Instruments through the terminal window using the following command:

```
$ instruments -t Time\ Profiler "/Applications/.../<app_name>.app" <arguments>

e.g. $ instruments -t Time\ Profiler "/Applications/MyApp.app" "/Users/<username>/Desktop/TestFiles/file.txt"
```

The command when passed to os.system is working fine, but the problem with this is that it waits till the application is quit:

```
os.system("echo %s | sudo -S %s" % (password,trace_launch_cmd))
```

but when I use Subprocess.Popen() it is giving error :

App launch failed with error : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'instruments -t Time\ Profiler "/Applications/MyApp.app"'

I also tried to split the command using shlex.split() and then using it in subprocess.Popen but then it is doing nothing.

```
app_launch_path = r'/Applications/MyApp.app'
trace_cmd = r'instruments -t Time\ Profiler '
app_launch_with_testfile = '"' + app_launch_path + '" ' + '"' + testfile_full_path + '"'
trace_launch_cmd = trace_cmd + app_launch_with_testfile
os.system("echo %s | sudo -S %s" % (password,trace_launch_cmd))
```

Comment: So, there were issues with quotes in my application path. I am now escaping the quotes with '\' and now not getting the App launch failed error but instead nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Using the subprocess library is generally the right way to go.

If you want to start a subprocess for something like `echo <something> | sudo -S <something>`, you need to execute it through the shell because there are multiple commands, linked with a pipe. You can do that by passing `shell=True` to the `Popen` call. `shlex` should not be required.

Aside: subprocess also allows you to pass input to the program directly, so that you do not need to use `echo` and the shell, see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for the `stdin` argument and the `communicate()` call.

Comment: I have tried it with shell=True also but then also it is not working.